# The images in my react-app carrousel are not caching, they are redownloaded on every render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, image, performance

I'm working on a react-app showcasing some of my photos. My images are all stored locally under my public folder. To render these images, I first wrote a data collection of my images in a JSON file, that is stored under a utils folder. There are 2 types of images: photo and illustration. Based on what type of image, I toggle between them by filtering the JSON data and rerendering them.

I then render the filtered images using a map function, and I'm using a picture tag for performance/art direction reasons.

I noticed some slow loading of the images when I filter, even though all the images are optimized. I checked the network panel and noticed that every time I switch the filter from photo to illustration or vice versa, the images are redownloaded and are not coming from the memory cache. How can I save my and future users' bandwidth?

I first of all tried lazy loading my images, so installed a new dependency for lazy loading, but that's not where the problem lies. I have a feeling the problem lies with how I approach image rendering. It might be due to the fact that I'm using a JSON files' data to render the images? I honestly have no clue. I did some research regarding caching, and the browser is supposed to do this automatically when you're using img tags. I also checked my devtools if caching was disabled, but that's not the case.

My JSON file structure (editorialData)

```
{
  "editorial": [
    {
      "fallback": "images/photos/jpg/DSCF0369.jpg",
      "webp": "images/photos/webp/DSCF0369.webp",
      "title": "Photography",
      "date": "2022-09-01",
      "type": "photography",
      "category": "street"
    },
    {
      "fallback": "images/photos/jpg/DSCF1325.jpg",
      "webp": "images/photos/webp/DSCF1325.webp",
      "title": "Photography",
      "date": "2022-09-24",
      "type": "photography",
      "category": "street"
    },
]
}
```

Here is the code of the page where I load my images:

```
import editorialData from "../../../../utils/editorial.json"
import { useDraggable } from "react-use-draggable-scroll"
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react"
import ArrowReturn from "../../../../assets/icons/ArrowReturn"
import { LazyLoadImage } from "react-lazy-load-image-component"

export default function Editorial() {
  const photosRef = useRef(null)
  const photosTrackerRef = useRef()
  const [photoProgress, setPhotoProgress] = useState(0)
  const [radioState, setRadioState] = useState("photo")

  const { events: events1 } = useDraggable(photosRef, {
    safeDisplacement: 11,
    decayRate: 0.6, // specify the drag sensitivity
  })

  const maxWidth = (ref) => {
    if (ref) {
      return ref.scrollWidth - ref.clientWidth
    }
  }

  const windowWidth = window.innerWidth


//this useEffect regards to a progress bar, indicating how far the user scrolls through the carrousel
  useEffect(() => {
    const calculateTrackerWidth = (ref, progress) => {
      return Math.round(
        (windowWidth / 100) * ((progress / maxWidth(ref)) * 100)
      )
    }

    photosTrackerRef.current.style.setProperty(
      "--PhotosTrackerWidth",
      Math.round(
        (calculateTrackerWidth(photosRef.current, photoProgress) /
          windowWidth) *
          100
      ) + "%"
    )
  }, [windowWidth, photoProgress])

  function sortDesc(a, b) {
    return new Date(b.date).getTime() - new Date(a.date).getTime()
  }


//here I filter the images based on the selected filter    photo/illustration
  const filterOnRadioState = () => {
    let filteredImgs

    if (radioState === "photo") {
      filteredImgs = editorialData.editorial.filter(
        (img) => img.type === "photography"
      )
    } else if (radioState === "illustration") {
      filteredImgs = editorialData.editorial.filter(
        (img) => img.type === "illustration"
      )
    }
    return filteredImgs.sort(sortDesc)
  }

//useEffect throttling the progress bar mentioned above
  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      if (photosRef) {
        setPhotoProgress(photosRef.current.scrollLeft)
      }
    }, 300)
    return () => clearInterval(timer)
  }, [])

//state change handler for the photo/illustration toggle
  const onOptionChange = (e) => {
    setRadioState(e.target.value)
    photosRef.current.scrollLeft = 0
    setPhotoProgress(0)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div ref={photosTrackerRef} className="photoTracker"></div>

      <div
        onClick={() => (photosRef.current.scrollLeft = 0)}
        className={`return_zero${photoProgress > 800 ? "" : " hidden"}`}>
        <ArrowReturn />
      </div>

      <div className="radio_btn-wrapper">
        <div
          className={`label_highlight${
            radioState === "photo" ? "" : " highlight_right"
          }`}></div>
        <div className="radio_btn">
          <input
            type="radio"
            name="radio"
            id="photo"
            value={"photo"}
            checked={radioState === "photo"}
            onChange={onOptionChange}
          />
          <label
            className="photo_label"
            htmlFor="photo"
            style={
              radioState === "photo" ? { color: "var(--fourthGrey)" } : null
            }>
            Photography
          </label>
        </div>

        <div className="radio_btn">
          <input
            type="radio"
            name="radio"
            value={"illustration"}
            id="illustration"
            checked={radioState === "illustration"}
            onChange={onOptionChange}
          />
          <label
            className="illustration_label"
            htmlFor="illustration"
            style={
              radioState === "illustration"
                ? { color: "var(--fourthGrey)" }
                : null
            }>
            Illustration
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="photos_wrapper" ref={photosRef} {...events1}>
        {filterOnRadioState().map((props, index) => {
          return (
            <picture className="photo_img">
              <source type="image/webp" srcSet={props.webp}></source>
              <source type="image/jpeg" srcSet={props.fallback}></source>
              <LazyLoadImage
                key={index}
                type="image"
                className="editorial_img"
                src={props.url}
                alt={props.title}></LazyLoadImage>
            </picture>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: And does this also happen in a production version of React or is it just in development? Context about your build system would be helpful like are you using CRA, Vite, Next.js, Gatsby etc.?

Comment: I did check my production build and it's exactly the same issue. I am not really advanced with coding terms since Im still a fairly newbie frontender; but I built my code and published it using Netlify for testing purposes. I don't have any backend by the way. Code is bundled using babel

Comment: Are you certain you are using Babel as a bundler? AFAIK Babel is a transformer and does not bundle code. A bundler would be something like webpack, swc, rollup or parcel. Regardless, your browser should cache images with the `Cache-Control` header, this is 100% unrelated to React (a ui JS library). You can easily check this, first start your app in production mode (locally works just as well) and then run `curl -L -I <link to image>` and inspect the headers.

Comment: My apologies, I am using webpack and yarn for this! Misinterpreted your question. Where would I run this snippet you're suggesting? In my terminal? I would doubt that my cache-control is altered, I haven't heard or even touched this.